# Microsoft modeling language?

Tags: modeling

I remember reading about a modeling language developed by Microsoft as a UML alternative, and it wasn't 'M' or 'Oslo'. Can anybody tell me the name?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft often espouses the virtues of domain-specific languages (DSLs) and encourages designers to follow that path. You could, however, be recalling [Codename "D"](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-declares-its-modeling-love-with-a-new-language-d/1159) which was/is developed as a model-driven approach to development.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its called the 'Oslo Modeling Language'.

A quick search on the Microsoft Research portal answered your question - http://bit.ly/cGtNGH < Theres a Link.

I don't know if its released etc, just that it exists.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd285282.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Oslo was the name for the Microsoft strategy for model-driven development consisting in the M modeling language + the Quadrant modeling environment + a model repository

M is a developer friendly, textual language for defining schemas, queries, values, functions and DSLs. In this sense, M is not exaxtly a UML alternative but, simplifying a lot, a language to create what in UML we call class diagrams.

The problem is that unfortunately [Microsoft is rethinking (dropping?) its MDD strategy](http://modeling-languages.com/blog/content/microsoft-dropping-quadrant-another-step-backwards-its-mdd-strategy)